# character encoding about content-type

Tags: spring-boot, google-chrome, safari, character-encoding, content-type

Backend server : springboot 2.6.3

Case1, Http Request
Get * HTTP1/1
Accept: */*

Http Response
Content-Type: application/json or application/json;charset=UTF-8

1. In mobile, when I request at Chrome & Safari browser,
   response entity content-type is "application/json",
   there is a character encoding problem about korean or else character
2. In mobile, when I request at Chrome & Safari browser,
   response entity content-type is "application/json;charset=UTF-8",
   there is no problem character encoding about korean or else character

Q: what is different between application/json and application/json;charset=UTF-8?
; The reason, no problem character encoding "application/json;charset=UTF-8"

Case2, Http Request
Get * HTTP1/1
Accept: */*

Http Response
Content-Type: application/json or application/json;charset=UTF-8

1. In pc, when i request at Chrome, response entity content-type is
   "application/json;charset=UTF-8", or "application/json;charset=UTF-8"
   there is no problem charactor encoding about korean or else character

Q: Regardless content-type, why pc browser has nothing problem about character encoding?

plz save me... i wanna go home ... plz..

Comment: UTF-8 is an encoding of Unicode, so it can encode practically all languages (but few fictional ones). -- And web is since many years UTF-8 by default (since HTML5). Explicit is often better then implicit, but your preferences matter

Answer (score 0):

if you have content-type content'charset=UTF-8',you will have 'charset=UTF-8'.if you
do not have it, the PC system  or mobile system have default charset. maby you see a wrong char.  especially chinese application soft

Comment: The encoding type of the server response should match the indicated encoding in content-type, thus if you use UTF-8 do indicate it. Also, I recommend adding a ref link, in this case: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Type

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).